# How to reverse string in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I wrote below code to reverse string , but it does not work. It says s[left] is read-only.

```
public string ReverseString(string s) {
    int left = 0;
    int right=s.Length - 1;
    while(left < right){
        char temp = s[left];
        s[left] = s[right];
        s[right] = temp;
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Yes, should use StringBuilder as string is immutable in .net
private string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
            int left = 0;
            int right = s.Length - 1;
            while (left < right)
            {
                char temp = sb[left];
                sb[left] = sb[right];
                sb[right] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

Comment: `public string Reverse(string text)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = text.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
                sb.Append(text[i]);

            return sb.ToString();                        
        }`